# VBA Runtime error 6: overflow on one calculation, but other calculations work

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, overflow

I'm trying to run the following code, but I'm getting a runtime error 6: overflow for the last calculation that I am trying to do. The program stops when it reaches `MLtot = MLwin / (MLwin + MLloss)`. The other two calculations can be done without issues.

I've also tried setting my variable to different data types to solve the issue, but without luck.

```
Sub AutoWinPercent()

    Dim Swin As Variant, Sloss As Variant, OUwin As Variant, OUloss As Variant
    Dim MLwin As Variant, MLloss As Variant
    Dim Stot As Double, OUtot As Double, MLtot As Double

    For i = 1 To 17
        Swin = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A258"), i, Range("Y3:Y258"), "WIN")
        Sloss = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A258"), i, Range("Y3:Y258"), "LOSS")
        OUwin = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A258"), i, Range("Z3:Z258"), "WIN")
        OUloss = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A258"), i, Range("Z3:Z258"), "LOSS")
        MLwin = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A258"), i, Range("AA3:AA258"), "WIN")
        MLloss = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A3:A258"), i, Range("AA3:AA258"), "LOSS")
        
        j = i + 2   'sets the starting row of where the percentages will be placed.
        
        Stot = Swin / (Swin + Sloss)
        OUtot = OUwin / (OUwin + OUloss)
        MLtot = MLwin / (MLwin + MLloss)
        
        Range("AC" & j).Value = Stot     'Spread
        Range("AD" & j).Value = OUtot    'OU
        Range("AE" & j).Value = MLtot  'ML
        
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: maybe add Debug.Print MLwin, MLloss just before the calcualtion.

Comment: @Blitzer It looks like it errors out whenever it runs into an instance when it tries to divide 0. I added `On Error Resume Next` after I declared the variables and it resolved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the overflow error is due to division by zero, consider a user defined function to check zeroes in denominator and conditionally handle calculation as needed. Avoid the `On Error Resume Next` quick fix as it will suppress other errors and makes it difficult to debug issues.

Additionally, as best practice in VBA, be sure to qualify all objects (i.e., `.Range` to Worksheet, Worksheet to Workbook). Below uses `With` block. Please adjust for actual sheet name. Also, `Dim` all variables used such as `i` and `j` (unless publicly declared).

**Function** *(place in same module as `Sub` or standard module)*

```vb
Function CalcExpression(numerator As Variant, denominator As Variant) As Variant
   Dim val As Variant

   If denominator = 0 Then
       val = ""
   Else 
       val = numerator / denominator 
   End If

   CalcExpression = val   
End Function
```

**Subroutine**

```vb
Sub AutoWinPercent()
On Error Goto ErrHandler

    Dim Swin As Variant, Sloss As Variant
    Dim OUwin As Variant, OUloss As Variant 
    Dim MLwin As Variant, MLloss As Variant 
    Dim Stot As Variant, OUtot As Variant, MLtot As Variant 
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("myWorksheet") 
        For i = 1 To 17 
             Swin = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A3:A258"), i, .Range("Y3:Y258"), "WIN")
             Sloss = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A3:A258"), i, .Range("Y3:Y258"), "LOSS") 
             OUwin = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A3:A258"), i, .Range("Z3:Z258"), "WIN") 
             OUloss = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A3:A258"), i, .Range("Z3:Z258"), "LOSS") 
             MLwin = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A3:A258"), i, .Range("AA3:AA258"), "WIN") 
             MLloss = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("A3:A258"), i, .Range("AA3:AA258"), "LOSS") 

             Stot = CalcExpression(Swin, (Swin + Sloss))
             OUtot = CalcExpression(OUwin, (OUwin + OUloss))
             MLtot = CalcExpression(MLwin, (MLwin + MLloss))
              
             j = i + 2 'sets the starting row of where the percentages will be placed. 

             .Range("AC" & j).Value = Stot 'Spread 
             .Range("AD" & j).Value = OUtot 'OU 
             .Range("AE" & j).Value = MLtot 'ML
         Next i
    End With

ExitHandler:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "RUNTIME ERROR"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```